# jstree Enable a node and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, children

I am using:

```
jstree("disable_node", "#" + NodeID);
```

to disable a node in jstree. and using:

```
jstree("enable_node", "#" + NodeID);
```

to enable a node.

Is there a simple way to `disable/enable` a node and it's children?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the code as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/02ky8n2w/).

1. Write a recursive function to iterate multi-level structures

   ```
   function changeStatus(node_id, changeTo) {
       var node = $("#tree").jstree().get_node(node_id);
       if (changeTo === 'enable') {
           $("#tree").jstree().enable_node(node);
           node.children.forEach(function(child_id) {
               changeStatus(child_id, changeTo);
           })
       } else {
           $("#tree").jstree().disable_node(node);
           node.children.forEach(function(child_id) {
               changeStatus(child_id, changeTo);
           })
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call function depending on what you need

   ```
   changeStatus(NodeID, 'enable');
   ```

   or

   ```
   changeStatus(NodeID, 'disable');
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I write a simple JS function based on `jstree` [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=get_node&f=get_node%28obj%20[,%20as_dom]%29) about `get_node` function and `jstree` [JSON](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) data format that `enable/disable` the input node and all it's child in any level:

```
    NodeToggleEnable = function (node_id, enable) {
        var tree = $("#jstree-locations");
        var sub_tree = [node_id.toString()];
        var index = 0;
    while (index < children.length) {
        var child = tree.jstree("get_node", "#" + children[index]).children;
        sub_tree = sub_tree.concat(child);
        if (enable == false)
            tree.jstree("disable_node", "#" + sub_tree[index]);
        else
            tree.jstree("enable_node", "#" + sub_tree[index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

this function uses `children`(array of strings or objects) property of node that selected by `get_node` function.